# Authorization error on the UI in HealthChecks.UI using the UI (/healthchecks-ui endpoint) but works fine when calling the JSON endpoint (/health)

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, unauthorized, health-check, authorize

UPDATE:

I definitely have some sort of deep-rooted authentication problem. This doesn't really have anything to do with the HeakthCheck.UI project I don't think.

I set up a simple test controller and when I run it locally it returns the data. But I went to a QA server and debugged on the server and it is definitely returning as Unauthorized.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    HealthCheckViewModel model = new();

    using HttpClient client = new();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync($"https://mywebsite.com/health");
    var testResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    return View(model);
}
```

---

ORIGINAL:

I am getting an Unauthorized error in the UI of healthchecks-ui. Calling /health alone works fine. Everything even works fine in my localhost environment. I have an assumption that there is a problem passing the authentication token through. However, the /health endpoint seems to be obeying the Roles I have set up so it is partially working with the bearer token. Everything is .net 8.0.

I am using Azure AD (Entra ID) for authentication. To get to my site at all you need to log in with a Microsoft account linked to AAD and have the appropriate permissions. All of the permissions work fine throughout the site and even in the /health endpoint.

Ultimately I would like to use the HealthChecks.UI actual UI and not the JSON because it is a lot prettier and has the 5 second polling retry.

**website.com/health** = loads fine and returns this JSON:
{"status":"Healthy","totalDuration":"00:00:01.1584121","entries":{"sqlserver":{"data":{},"duration":"00:00:01.1117668","status":"Healthy","tags":[]}}}

**website.com/healthchecks-ui** = loads fine, but the health check says "unhealthy". The exact error is:
`HTTP response is not in valid state (Unauthorized) when trying to get report from /health configured with name All Health Checks.`

The error can be found here in the source code: https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks/blob/73abc7a094f9ef625b83455898a21d22d2fa6a82/src/HealthChecks.UI/Core/HostedService/HealthCheckReportCollector.cs#L147

I set up a very simple example that demonstrates the problem.

Here is the service registration:

`services.AddHealthChecks().AddSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("OpkCoreDatabaseProduction")); services.AddHealthChecksUI().AddInMemoryStorage();`

Here is the endpoint registration:

```
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "areas",
        pattern: "{area}/{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{area=General}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapGraphQL("/graphql");
    endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health", new HealthCheckOptions
    {
        ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse,
    }).AllowAnonymous();
    endpoints.MapHealthChecksUI().AllowAnonymous();
});
```

Here is the appsettings.json setup:
  `"HealthChecksUI": { "HealthChecks": [ { "Name": "All Health Checks", "Uri": "/health" } ], "EvaluationTimeInSeconds": 5 } }`

Here is my Authorization setup:
`services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));`

[This is what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0E9WT.png)

**QUESTION: Am I missing somewhere that I set up the header to be passed along?**

I've tried all sorts of flavors of AddAuthorization() and AllowAnonymous() and they all seem to work for /heath but I can't get /healthchecks-ui to authorize.

I've attempted to debug this on the server as I cannot reproduce it using localhost. Nothing of value has turned up because I cannot debug the actual code library where the problem lies.

I've also tried changing the endpoints to have a Uri of "https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/health" and other variations.

There is a similar problem here: [AspNetCore Health Checks UI could not get endpoint URI from configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77859239/aspnetcore-health-checks-ui-could-not-get-endpoint-uri-from-configuration)

Their solution was to set IIS to allow anonymous, but I don't want my whole site to be publicly accessible.

Comment: Please check, the authentication token is passed along correctly, you might need to configure your HttpClient to include the authentication token in its requests. You can do this by setting the Authorization header with the token value.

Comment: Thanks. I can do that in my own code in the controller. I cannot update the HttpClient in the HealthChecks library, though. There has to be some sort of middleware to set the header on all requests. I have looked into the HeaderPropagation library for .net core, but I haven't been able to figure it out yet.